# About a PyQt example program

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm currently need GUI library for a project. I'm familiar with python and found PyQt might be a good choice.

I'm reading [a tutorial about PyQt](https://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/), and quite confused about the following [example program](https://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/drawing/)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
ZetCode PyQt4 tutorial 

In this example, we draw text in Russian azbuka.

author: Jan Bodnar
website: zetcode.com 
last edited: September 2011
"""

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
    
        self.initUI()
    
    def initUI(self):      

        self.text = u'\u041b\u0435\u0432 \u041d\u0438\u043a\u043e\u043b\u0430\
\u0435\u0432\u0438\u0447 \u0422\u043e\u043b\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0439: \n\
\u0410\u043d\u043d\u0430 \u041a\u0430\u0440\u0435\u043d\u0438\u043d\u0430'

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('Draw text')
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):

        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.drawText(event, qp)
        qp.end()
    
    def drawText(self, event, qp):
  
        qp.setPen(QtGui.QColor(168, 34, 3))
        qp.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Decorative', 10))
        qp.drawText(event.rect(), QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, self.text)        
            
    
def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here, in main function, an Example object is created, thus `__init__()` function, `initUI()` is called.
My question is where does `paintEvent()` function is called?? since if we run the program, `self.text(some Russian letters)` will exactly appear on the widget.

In other words, what does `sys.exit(app.exec_())` actually do? why it will call `paintEvent()` function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [PyQt docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qapplication.html#exec):

> `int QApplication.exec_ ()`
>
> Enters the main event loop and waits until `exit()` is called, then
>   returns the value that was set to `exit()` (which is 0 if `exit()` is
>   called via `quit()`).
>
> It is necessary to call this function to start event handling. The
>   main event loop receives events from the window system and dispatches
>   these to the application widgets.

From [another source](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/firstprograms/):

> `sys.exit(app.exec_())`
>
> Finally, we enter the mainloop of the
>   application. The event handling starts from this point. The mainloop
>   receives events from the window system and dispatches them to the
>   application widgets. The mainloop ends, if we call the `exit()` method
>   or the main widget is destroyed. The `sys.exit()` method ensures a clean
>   exit. The environment will be informed, how the application ended.
>
> The `exec_()` method has an underscore. It is because the `exec` is a
>   Python keyword. And thus, `exec_()` was used instead.

About [painting](http://tinf2.vub.ac.be/~dvermeir/manual/KDE20Development-html/ch04lev1sec2.html):

> **4.2.1. When Painting Occurs**
>
> The `paintEvent()` method is called automatically when
>
> - Your widget is shown for the first time.
> - After a window has been moved to reveal some part (or all) of the
>     widget.
> - The window in which the widget lies is restored after being minimized.
> - The window in which the widget lies is resized.
> - The user switches from another desktop to the desktop on which the
>     widget's window lies.
>
> You can generate paint events manually by calling `QWidget::update()`.
>   `QWidget::update()` erases the widget before generating the paint event.
>   You can pass arguments to `update()`, which can restrict painting only
>   to areas (rectangles, in particular) that need it. The two equivalent
>   forms of the method are `QWidget::update (int x, int y, int width, int
>   height)` and `QWidget::update (QRect rectangle)`, where `x` and `y` give the
>   upper-left corner of the rectangle, and width and height are obvious.
>   Because `update()` places a paint event into the event queue, no
>   painting occurs until the current method exits and control returns to
>   the event handler. This is a good thing because other events may be
>   waiting there to be processed, and events need to be processed in a
>   timely manner for the GUI to operate smoothly.
>
> You can also invoke painting of the widget by calling `QWidget::repaint (int x, int y, int width, int height, bool erase)` (or one of several
>   convenience-method forms), where all the arguments mean the same as in
>   the case of the `update()` method, and erase tells repaint whether to
>   erase the rectangle before painting it. `repaint()` calls `paintEvent()`
>   directly. It does not place a paint event into the event queue, so use
>   this method with care. If you try to call `repaint()` repeatedly from a
>   simple loop to create an animation, for example, the animation will be
>   drawn, but the rest of your user interface will be unresponsive
>   because the events corresponding to mouse button clicks, keyboard
>   presses, and so on will be waiting in the queue. Even if you are not
>   performing a task as potentially time-consuming as animation, it is
>   generally better to use `update()` to help keep your GUI alive.
>
> If you paint something on your widget outside the `paintEvent()`, you
>   still need to include the logic and commands necessary to paint that
>   same thing in `paintEvent()`. Otherwise, the painting you did would
>   disappear the next time the widget is updated.

Comment: Thank you for your such detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It becomes more clear when one has some experience with low level programming,
for example in Winapi or the X toolkit in C language. PyQt is a (very) high level toolkit. 
It comes with a huge built-in functionality. Similar example would require hundreds or maybe thousands of lines of C code. As a consequence, there is a lot of going on 
behind the scenes. Somebody already created code that deals with painting on a basic level.
GUI programming is very complex and with modern GUI toolkits the application programmer is shielded from this complexity. It is inevitable that programmers are confused if they do not know all the technical details.

In PyQt, we are essentially dealing with events in two ways. We connect signals to slots or reimplement event handlers (an event handler is a synonym for a slot). The provided example inherited from the `QtGui.QWidget` which already has some painting code available.
In order to do our custom painting, we have to reimplement the existing `paintEvent()` event
handler. Depending on the situation, we may or may not call the parent's `paintEvent()` method.

The `sys.exit(app.exec_())` does not call the `paintEvent()` method. The `exec_()` method starts an event loop. The event loop catches and dispatches events. Paint events are triggered by users or by the operating system. For example, when we launch the example, the
paint event is triggered twice. (Put a `print "Event occurred"` line in the event handler to see how many times this method is called.) Resizing windows, loosing or gaining focus, minimizing or maximizing windows, all these cause painting events to be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

`app.exec_()` starts the qt main loop, which ends when every created widget is destroyed (e.g. by closing its window). The `paintEvent` function is a method that you can overload from a `QWidget` subclass like the given `Example` class, which gets called when QT displays, updates or repaints the Widget.

You can look up these things in the [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#paintEvent) or the [PyQt Documentation](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwidget.html#paintEvent) (which is mostly just a copy of the QT Documentation in a different format, but sometimes contains some valuable information regarding PyQt-specific things).