# How can I force a repaint in PySide?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyside, paint

I have what I think is a repainting issue with a PySide widget. How can I force the widget (or the whole window/app) to repaint in the middle of a method?

```
def on_button_clicked():

    window.resultTextEdit.setPlainText("Parsing file...")
    # indicate delay, this message should be visible while parsing
    # but in fact it never appears

    # can I force a repaint here?

    result = parse() # (takes a little while)

    window.resultTextEdit.setPlainText(result)
    # display the results once done

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtUiTools.QUiLoader().load("application.ui")
window.userButton.clicked.connect(on_button_clicked)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11806126/4720935

Comment: @Mel great link, thanks! I've extracted the relevant bits as an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any widget that needs a repaint in the middle of an event, you can simply call `widget.repaint()`. Note that the rest of UI is unresponsive during the repaint (which is fine for a one-off call, but not if you're repainting repeatedly).

(Thanks Mel for pointing me to https://stackoverflow.com/a/11806126/4720935 )

Comment: It is recommended to use `widget.update()` instead of repaint